# How to query based off another table`s field?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table that has two columns. 
  FirstTable 
     UID, TID

And another table that has:
   SecondTable
     UID, TID, DiffColumn

I need to query if the UID OR TID of a user is in the FirstTable, given his UID and DiffColumn.
So I would need to join with the SecondTable to get the TID.

I tried using the following query:

```
     SELECT F.UID, F.TID FROM
      FirstTable F
     INNER JOIN 
     SecondTable S
     ON  F.UID = S.UID
     UNION
     SELECT F.UID, F.TID FROM
     FirstTable F
     INNER JOIN 
     SecondTable S ON  F.TID = S.TID
     WHERE S.DiffColumn= ''
     AND S.UID = ''
```

But I think I am overcomplicating this query and the where clause would apply to the second select statement only.
How would I best simplify this?

Comment: What if there is a match using both columns?  Which value do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` in the `ON` clause to merge both sub subqueries. You can also move the `WHERE` clause's content to the  `ON`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    f.uid,
    f.tid
FROM 
    firsttable f
INNER JOIN 
    secondtable s ON s.uid = f.uid
                  OR s.tid = f.tid
                  AND s.tid = ''
                  AND s.uid = '';
```

Comment: I had to edit the query, because the where clause was wrong.
I had Where S.TID = '', and it was supposed to be S.DiffColumn = '', since that is the value I have. I will try this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a prioritization where the match on `uid` takes precedence over the match on `tid`, then use two `left join`s:

```
select f.uid, f.tid,
       coalesce(su.?, st.?) as ?  -- ? is a column you might want from secondtable
from firsttable f left join
     secondtable su
     on su.uid = f.uid left join
     secondtable st
     on st.tid = f.tid and
        st.diffcolumn = '' and
        st.uid = ''
where st.uid is not null or st.tid is not null;
```

Alternatively you can just use `exists` if you don't want any columns from `secondtable`:

```
select f.*
where exists (select 1
              from secondtable su
              where su.uid = f.uid
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from secondtable st
              where st.tid = f.tid and
                    st.diffcolumn = '' and
                    st.uid = ''
     );
```

Although you can use `or` in the correlation clause rather than two `exists`s, I strongly discourage it.  `or` in `on` clauses and correlation clauses and be a performance killer.